# How to switch between multiple versions of Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, version

I need to provide maintenance support for the "legacy" mobile App, while also providing enhanced feature support to the "next major version" of this mobile App.  To do it efficiently, I need to be able to switch between 1.3.x and 1.4.x of the Kotlin compiler.  Everything that I am reading, implies that Kotlin only moves forward, so I hesitate to upgrade my version of Kotlin in Android Studio to get 1.4.x plugin installed without the confidence that I can switch back to 1.3.x.

It looks like a simple change in the Gradle build scripts should work, but it is not clear that changing the version changes all of the toolset, or simply tries to be backward compatible from a future-looking configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the Android Studio plugin safely - it should be backward compatible with the older versions of Kotlin.

If you want to change the compiler version (for using new language features), you should update the version in the Gradle script - you can change it whenever you want, the older versions of Kotlin libs and compiler are still available in the repositories.

I recommend you to always update Android Studio plugin to the latest version, so you have full Kotlin support in your IDE for all versions of the Kotlin compiler.

Comment: In general I agree with the recommendation to always upgrade, however, I have a DevOps CI/CD that supports the production app that will not upgrade for the time-being.  So, I want to ensure that the Dev Team when performing maintenance, is using the same Kotlin toolset (frameworks, plugins, etc.); meanwhile, they are building new features with the latest Kotlin toolset.  Can one just change versions in gradle configuration files?  How do I ensure that the down-level toolset is downloaded and used?

Comment: @mobibob First of all, I should notice that Android Studio plugin is not a part of CI/CD pipeline, so it doesn't affect the build itself but provides language support in the IDE. To use the latest Kotlin features, you should update the Kotlin version in the gradle configs. Gradle will download the proper Kotlin version by itself when building the app. So, no need to check anything manually. There might be an issue if you're getting the Kotlin version from the CI/CD environment - if you're not able to change this and use the latest Kotlin features, the code will not compile.